# XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url] Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http, cloud9

I'm making an ionic app for android and today I implemented a server side nodejs (express) Restful API with mongodb on cloud9.

But when I trigger a http request to the url, I keep getting the error mentioned in the title:

This is my angular http request on ionic (simply to test first):

```
app.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) { 
    $http.get('https://[workspace]-[user].c9users.io/api/capture')
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

This is an image of my workspace:

[image: workspace]

I used the following code to make the database:
api.js

```
var Capture = require('../models/capture');
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.get('/capture', function(req, res){
        var capture = new Capture();
        // capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
        // capture.place.city = req.place.body.city;
        // capture.place.country = req.place.body.country;

        capture.birdname = "Pigeon";

        capture.save(function(err, data){
            if(err)
                throw err;

            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.get('/captures', function(req, res){
        Customer.find({}, function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
        })
    })
}
```

capture.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var captureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    birdname: String,
    place: {
        city: String,
        country: String   
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Capture', captureSchema)
```

database.js

```
module.exports = {
    'url': 'mongodb://' + process.env.IP
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./server/config/database.js');

mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

var api = express.Router();
require('./server/routes/api')(api);
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT)
```

Anyone have an idea why I'm getting this error and what I need to do to fix this?
I'm guessing it has something to do with the server allowing me to send requests to the API though I don't know how to implement that.

Is there also a way to secure my database (API key maybe) and how would I implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response for preflight is invalid in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481764/response-for-preflight-is-invalid-in-angular)