# Response for preflight is invalid in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to perform test using apiary api as the following:

```
 $scope.createAsset = function () {
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://polls.apiblueprint.org/createStory',
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});
}
```

Apiary:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://polls.apiblueprint.org/
# BulBulTest
BulBulTest is a simple API for testing.

## Create story [/createStory]
### Create story [POST]

+ Response 200 (application/json)       
{
    "Status": "Story created sucessfully",
    "published_at": "2015-08-05T08:40:51.620Z",
    "publisher": "Johm Smith"
}
```

and I get error even after setting the `allow-origin`.

Comment: Well you are setting request headers, is the server responsing with proper response headers?

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header needs to be set via the server not the client. So there will be an OPTIONS request (aka the pre flight check). This request should respond with all the Access Control jazz.

Comment: Please share the server side code. I don't think there is anything wrong at the client end.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding of [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/): The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header comes from the **server**, not the client. It's the server that decides whether to allow a cross-origin call.

There's nothing you can do in your *client-side* code to enable a cross-origin call if the server doesn't support it.

Comment: I am using grunt server to run app locally

Comment: If you're running the server app locally then why you're making a request to `url: "http://headers.jsontest.com/"`  your server files will be available in `http://localhost:<port number>/`

Comment: I want to create a test api using apiary

Comment: *"I am using grunt server to run app locally"* The server that grants access isn't **your** server, it's the `http://polls.apiblueprint.org` server.

Comment: really? I guess its the problem of security that trying to access from local host to http site. What if I have my app loaded in to heroku or openshift and then try to access the apiary test api?

Comment: @Satyadev: Any *cross-origin* request (localhost -> apiary, heroku -> apiary, etc.) will be prevented by the Same Origin Policy unless the *server* receiving the request (apiary) allows requests from that origin. If their API is meant to  be used from browsers, they should support CORS and/or provide a JSONP alternative. If it's not meant to be queried from browsers, they won't, and youll need to do the query from *your server* (servers aren't subject to the SOP).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", but rather you might be missing some additional parameters since it is a POST call. If you have API method details then check what are the parameters required in "@RequestParams".Hope this might help.

Comment: Okay in that case can you just test this and tell me whether you are getting any response or not.

`$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://polls.apiblueprint.org/questions'
});`

Comment: Ya its working, but when I use `http://polls.apiblueprint.org/createStory` it says not found in the browser

Comment: Okay then I think there is some error in "create story" url. Please check the url once again.